# how print euro symbol with flutter and zebra printer?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have my flutter app that use cpcl commands to communicate with zebra zq220 printer. it works fine but doesn't print € euro symbol

here my function to create cpcl commands

```
List<String>lst=[];
lst.add("TEXT 4 2 0 80 € 12.9");
//HERE WITH OTHER COMMANDS AND FINALLY
String ss="";
for(int i=0;i<lst.length;++i)
{
ss+="${lst[i]}\r\n"
}
await sendByte(ss);
```

and here my function to send to my zebra printer

```
Future<void> sendByte(String scmd) async {
  
    List<BluetoothService> services = await connectDevice!.discoverServices();
    for (BluetoothService service in services) {
     
      var characteristics = service.characteristics;
     
      for (BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
        
//here are three encode type that work fine all with zebra printer, but they don't print euro symbol
           c.write(gbk.encode(scmd));
           //c.write(utf8.encode(scmd));
          //c.write(gbk_bytes.encode(scmd));
       
      }
    }
  }
```

So could someone help me to find the solution, how to print euro symbol with this??
Thanks in advance
Best Regards

Comment: Did you check the [CPCL for Link-OS Enabled Printers](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/printers/mobile/cpcl-programming-guide/cpcl-link-os-pg-en.pdf) manual? I don't write this into an answer since I cannot verify it, but on page 201 it says with the LATIN9 encoding you have a € sign available. Now you still have to figure out how to switch to that encoding ;-)

Comment: latin9 doesn't support my cpcl commands.It says: '[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Not a character in this code page (at character 19)'. So it doesn't even print.

Comment: oh, I just saw that I overlooked the € on page 198: without any codepage change, character 0x80 should be a €.

Comment: Yes,you are right, it finally works!!!  i write for flutter in this mode`  String a=String.fromCharCode(0x80); lst.add("TEXT 4 2 0 80 $a ${prezzoVendita.replaceAll(".", ",")}");     `.Thank you very very very much

Comment: can you write as an answear instead of comment??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the [CPCL for Link-OS Enabled Printers](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/printers/mobile/cpcl-programming-guide/cpcl-link-os-pg-en.pdf) manual.

On page 198 it says that - without any codepage change - character `0x80` should be a € sign.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the euro symbol by entering the escape character sequence into the string instead of the euro symbol.

The euro escape characters are highlighted in red below:

[image]

Comment: i tried i this mode `  const euroSymbol='\u0128';    ` and `lst.add("TEXT 4 2 0 80 $euroSymbol  12.3");`  but it prints nothing

Answer (score 0):

If i remember well, and if you use ZPL for communication with printer, you can send the `$` char to printer. Printer will print the good char if correctly parametered.

In my case it was a zebra label printer.

Comment: i use zebra zq220 printer and i use cpcl commands, some characters it doesn't take, if i use $ with a variable , and this variable is like="abc" then it prints nothing

Answer (score 0):

use

> $

before it, then copy euro sign after $

Comment: i tried what you said , it gives me error because in flutter can't write like this $€,it says 'Expected an identifier'. i tried also with ${€}

Answer (score 0):

Flutter supports writing unicode characters in strings. To do so you just have to find out the unicode value for like any character you want. For Euro it is `20AC`
And for putting Unicode values in strings you can try this

```
String a = '\u{20AC}' // \u shows unicode and in {} write the value of the unicode character.
```

Also zebra printer support typing euro keys
take a look at this [Printing the Euro Currency Symbol](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/printing-the-euro-currency-symbol.html).

Comment: thank you very much, i have tried what you said `  String a = '\u{20AC}';  lst.add("TEXT 4 2 0 80 $a ${prezzoVendita.replaceAll(".", ",")}");   ` but it doesn't work.  CRYING...

Comment: Have you tried the link which I posted?

Comment: I am posting it again: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/printing-the-euro-currency-symbol.html

Comment: yes i have seen this document but it says about zpl commands  and i'm using cpcl commands